# CSS spinning circle animation onClick gets choppy when run multiple times

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transforms

I have a CSS animation that uses a rotate using keyframes with transform rotate.

It works well the first time it is run - but if you run the animation multiple times using an onclick that adds the spin class it becomes choppier and choppier over time. 
Here is some code with a link to it in jsfiddle:

```
    <div class="row numRandoms">
         <h3>Winning Numbers:</h3>
         <div class="ball pickedIndex0" ></div>
         <div class="ball pickedIndex1" ></div>
         <div class="ball pickedIndex2" ></div>
         <div class="ball pickedIndex3" ></div>
    </div>

    .ball {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 4em;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 3.5%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset -25px -25px 40px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,220,.3) 0%,     transparent 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,220,.3) 0%, transparent 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,220,.3) 0%, transparent 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,220,.3) 0%, transparent 100%);
}
.spin {
        -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        -o-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    }}
@-o-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
    }}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }}
```

You can find the simple code in here: https://jsfiddle.net/vrhc4vet/

You can see it working live here: http://lottery-game.marycamacho.com

I can't tell if other aspects of my javascript are causing the degradation or if there is something inherent in the animation that has repeating it not work well.

I'm testing using the latest chrome browser.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Sorry, I can't reproduce "choppiness" in Firefox on Windows 10 in your jsfiddle. I tried adding the spin class via `classList.add("spin")` and `className += " spin"`; both animated smoothly.

Comment: @Jeremy -- the choppiness was not visible in the jsfiddle which clued me into that it was not a CSS issue but instead an issue with my javascript code. I refactored the code and found a sync problem with 2 separate timeouts and when I restructured it so that it was only 1, it smoothed it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code works perfectly - but the project did not. The deployed version has now been updated with my fix. The issue was deeper in the project - where I had inadvertently created 2 timeouts that were not working well together. I refactored the code so that only 1 timeout was used and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your code is working perfectly fine. The issue you're having could be the result of a slow internet connection. If this is so, you should still try and optimize your website because many people will experience this choppy animation in rural areas or places that generally have slow wireless internet connections. Here are a few things that could be slowing down your website.

Bootstrap, Bootstrap.js and  jQuery are all being loaded locally, even though they both have CDN's. You should change

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

to

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.2.min.js">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

to

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The integrity/crossorigin stuff is important for security reasons.
Another thing is that your page.js and styles.css files are both large, and you should probably [minify them](http://minifycode.com/).

There are many things you can do to optimize your websites. Here are some websites that could help you out:

[Google Developers Page Speed Test](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/)
[GTmetrix Website Speed and Performance Optimization](https://gtmetrix.com/)